# Why does a Triangular Fourier series converge faster than a Square Fourier series?

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-processing

I am currently taking a Fourier Analysis module in my Physics course and I was asked this question as a homework task which has caused me a great deal of confusion.

This attached [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y4u2.jpg) shows how the truncated series of both the triangular and square waves converge. In essence, why is it that the triangular series converges much quicker than the square series?

Edit: This is the actual [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdmPK.png) I got for all those curious.

Answer (score 3):

How do you want to look at it?

- Because the square wave has discontinuities in the waveform where the triangle wave only has discontinuities in the derivative, and these discontinuities require more high harmonics to reach a close approximation of the original waveform.
- Because the square wave has more energy in the high harmonics, cutting off the Fourier series at any given harmonic causes a bigger change in the square wave than in the triangle wave.